# How to go to next line in c?

Tags: c

Im trying to go to the next line in my terminal. Usually, in `printf()` I'd do this

```
printf("Hello\n")
```

However, is there a way to separate the `printf` function and the `\n` part?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by seperating them, but here are some examples:

1:

```
printf("Hello");
printf("\n");
```

2:

```
printf("Hello" "\n");
```

3: (seperate function)

```
void WriteLine(char* s)
{
   printf("%s\n",s);
}

WriteLine("Hallo");
```

4: (added the Answer from CodeWarrior)

```
#define println() printf("\n")
printf("Hello");
println();
```

But i might be even completely wrong on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could split them into two seperate printf() calls:

```
printf("Hallo");
printf("\n");
```

If you want to prettify it, you can define macros:

```
#define println() printf("\n")

printf("Hallo");
println();
```